# sql-Update multiple rows in a column with different values from a list dapper

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I have a ProjectTable and a ProjectMaterial mapping table. Each project can have multiple different materials associated to it.

ex;

```
 ProjectmaterialId   ProjectId   MaterialCode
      1                 4118      A
      2                 2135      B
      3                 4118      B
       ......
```

How can I update all the MaterialCode from one specific Project from a list of values?
I want the result should be something like:

```
ProjectmaterialId   ProjectId   MaterialCode
      1                 4118      c
      2                 2135      B
      3                 4118      D
       ......
```

as you realized I updated projectId 4118 from a list that had c,D values in it...
I am receiving the list of values from what the user updated on the View and I need to make this sql query to update the database using dapper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you

```
DECLARE @ProjectTable TABLE(ProjectmaterialId INT , ProjectId INT,   MaterialCode VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @ProjectTable

SELECT 1, 4118,     'A' union all
SELECT 2, 2135,     'B' union all
SELECT 3, 4118,     'B' 

DECLARE @ProjectMaterial  TABLE(ProjectmaterialId INT , ProjectId INT,   MaterialCode VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @ProjectMaterial 

SELECT 1, 4118  ,    'C' union all
SELECT 2, 2135  ,    'B' union all
SELECT 3, 4118  ,    'D' 

SELECT * from @ProjectTable
SELECT * from @ProjectMaterial 

UPDATE  A
SET MaterialCode=B.MaterialCode
FROM @ProjectTable A
INNER JOIN @ProjectTable B
ON A.ProjectmaterialId=B.ProjectmaterialId

SELECT * FROM @ProjectMaterial
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you explain a little bit because I'm very new to sql and I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: i  thoght that you want to update ProjectTable MaterialCode column with ProjectMaterial table MaterialCode  column

Comment: Also, the list from where I'm taking the values is a list of strings taken from a few tables together and I'm stuffing it into the property of the Project class in  dapper... and I want to update the DB according to the values of Project.Sources which is a list of strings...

Comment: No, I want to update the ProjectMaterial Table according to the values that the User updated for a specific project in the front-end. I get back a list of Materials.